# Debugging the VMware virtual network adapter vmxnet3 -- packets received by the adapter never make it to that port's listener

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, virtualization

Background: I have a virtual instance of Windows Server 2003 running from a VMware environment (although I only have access to the actual guest OS right now).  I have a custom .NET Windows service (full access to source) that is listening on a given port.

Problem: Client communication with this service began to degrade recently.  Specifically clients' packets randomly stop making it to the listening service.  Once a client's traffic fails to make it to the service it will never work again.  The odd thing is that with Wireshark I can see *every* request for the client.  But after that it's as though vmxnet3 drops that clients packets.  But only that client's packets.  Other clients are totally unaffected.  Also the service logs *every* single byte it receives and is a mature server.  Previously all servers and clients worked fine, the network adapter worked fine.  Nothing has changed in anything or been updated.

Some people have conjectured that packet drops are occurring because the rx buffers are full.  This suggestion was made because we were seeing "TCP ZeroWindowProbe" errors in Wireshark.  I doubt the rx buffers are full because the network utilization at that time was only 0.1%, and many other clients had their communications completely unaffected.

Question: How can I debug this adapter to more closely inspect what happens to a packet *after* it hits the virtual adapter?  How can I see which packets are dropped and why (whether it's a full rx buffer or not)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you use wireshark on the server (vm) to be sure packets are coming up to Windows ?

Comment: @MathieuChateau Yes.  I used Wireshark and can see the packets hit the virtual NIC.  After that...no idea.  It seems that the .NET runtime doesn't get these bytes.

Comment: so: all clients are working except one. Even packets for this specific client reach the network card of the server, but it's failing. Looks like on the issue is at the application level for me. Maybe this user is doing a specific things that hangs it's connection ?

Answer (score 2):

try enabling RSS on the vmxnet3 driver under the adapter properties.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of this.  I ended up rebuilding the Winsock catalog after seeing some odd hears, which solved the problem.  Fearing a compromise I just scrapped that instance altogether and reloaded a known good snapshot.